# Overcounting elements in conjugacy classes in a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My problem is overcounting when trying to figure out the number of elements in a conjugacy class in a symmetric group, in my case the symmetric group of degree 6.

In particular, when the representive element of a partition includes cycles that have the same number of elements inside them

The way I'm counting them at the moment is:

eg 6 = 3 + 2 + 1 ~ with representative element (1,2,3)(4,5) -  Count the number of elements in the conjugacy class

$$
( 6 \ choose \ 3) * \frac{3! \ permutations}{3 \ copies \ per \ element} *(3 \ choose  \ 2) * \frac{2! \ permutations}{2 \ copies \ per \ element} = 120
$$

Which I assume is fine unless I botched my way with luck to the solution somehow.

But when I try to apply that logic to say

6 = 2 + 2 + 2 ~ with representive element (1,2)(3,4)(5,6), three cycles with 2 in each

I know the answer is 15, and (6 choose 2) * (4 choose  2) = 90, you are double counting because (1,2) = (2,1) so diving by 2 gives you 45, now I need to justify dividing by 3 because I need to reach the solution 15. Is it simply because each representative element uses 3 pairs? If so how come

6 = 2 + 2 + 1 + 1: (1,2)(3,4) - I know the answer to counting the elements is 45

(6 choose 2) * (4 choose 2) = 90, and (1,2) = (2,1) so divide by two as you are double counting = 45, but by the same logic where I divided by 3 in the previous example because there were 3 pairs, I feel I was wrong as that would suggest I must now divide 45 by 2 to be consistent which is obviously wrong.

Any help clearing my overcounting issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you don't have to divide by $2$, because $(2,1) = (1,2)$. This has already been taken care for in the $\binom{6}{2}$ calculation. In fact after you found $90$ you have to divide by $3!=6$, as the three 2-cycles can be permuted in $3!$ ways. Now similarly you divide by $2!$ in the last example.

To sum it up shortly you don't double count because the element might appear in the different order in the cycle. In fact the double counting occurs because the cycles can change places and still give you the same permutation, as disjoint cycles commutate.

Comment: That cleared up a great deal for me, thank you. I'd upvote you if I wasnt such a low rep level! The fact that 2! = 2 confuses me sometimes because i cant tell if Im dividing by a factorial or just halfing. Thanks again.

Comment: @ConfusedPleb Don't worry mate. You can come back and upvote whenever you get over the 15 rep points limit ;). Anyway you should try to get the fundamental idea behind the result, not just automatically do it.

Answer (score 1):

You write every transposition with the left element as the smaller number and avoid counting $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ as different.  The element $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)$  and $(3,4)(1,2)(5,6)$ are one and the same (as they are products of commuting transpositions written in different order). As there are 6 permutations of these three participating transpositions, all yielding same result, the answer is $90/6=15$